# Windows 10 - Task scheduler (access denied when running .bat)

Tags: batch, scheduled-tasks

I have a .bat script, It just runs an .exe with arguments:

```
@echo off 
iperf -s -u -i 1 -f b >> 24htestS.log
```

The problem is that when I run the task scheduler I get access denied (even as a admin user)

Note: If I run the script manually it works perfectly

Any recommendation?

Comment: What user do you use to run the task? When you say run manually, do you have to right click and choose "run as admin" or do you run it just by clicking on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs run in the Task Scheduler need to specify paths and folders,
since the defaults are usually system folders.

You need to specify the full path to `iperf` and also add a
[cd command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cd),
or alternatively add the full path to the file `24htestS.log`.
Otherwise, you will be trying to save it in a system folder
where you don't have the access permissions
(not a good idea to run as Admin in order to force it).

Comment: Thank you very much that was the problem.  Already solved